# Repeated measures anova in R: comparing each month against itself across a ten year period

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, boxplot

I am an R novice and trying to perform a repeated measures anova to compare each month against the same month across all 10 years (e.g. Jan 2010, Jan 2011, Jan 2012 and so on... for each month). And then with the final results I would like to plot this into a boxplot as such with a new box for each month like in the image?

I have fiddled around on various tutorial but unable to reach a success. Any help appreciated thanks so much!

The code below is how I have been inputting the data into R to create the data.frame in the format below.

```
Year    Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec
2010    0      0      0      0      0      1      1      4      1      1      4      1                   
2011    0      1      0      1      1      3      7      0      0      2      2      1                   
2012    0      0      1      0      0      0      3      2      0      2      3      1                   
2013    2      2      2      6      6      2      33     17     18     9      9      3                      
2014    5      6      15     18     14     26     60     47     39     19     15     10                            
2015    10     22     14     24     26     57     110    94     82     73     38     17                               
2016    22     34     36     64     68     79     223    120    81     56     30     13                               
2017    23     27     50     82     70     140    243    197    112    102    59     27                                   
2018    42     39     94     140    116    209    384    297    165    124    93     49                                    
2019    37     54     64     127    115    684    178    148    87     67     31     27
```

[image: Would like to replicate this boxplot, with each month along the X axis, Jan, Feb, Mar..]

Comment: what do you mean by comparing each month against the same month? You want to know whether there is a effect of year within each month? And for the boxplot i guess the x-axis should be year?

Comment: You give data, suggest using ANOVA, showing boxplots, etc. But you give no clue what the purpose of your description and testing may be. Why do you care about differences among months? Are you trying to describe the past or predict the future?